# Ruby idiom to shortcircuit to return first non-nil using each and map

Tags: ruby, each

This is the essence of what I'm trying to do but the 'break' doesn't feed right:

```
needle = nil
haystacks.each do |haystack|
  needle = haystack.look_for_needle()
  break if needle
end
```

This is shorter, but it will iterate over every haystack (without looking at least) even though it doesn't need to:

```
needle = nil
haystacks.each do |haystack|
  needle ||= haystack.look_for_needle()
end
```

This is a one-liner but (I believe) it is not lazy and so it does unnecessary work:

```
needle = hackstacks.map{|h| h.look_for_needle()}.detect{|x| !x.nil?}
```

I feel like there should be a one liner, but I'm not sure it would be:

```
needle = hackstacks.some_find_each_first_detect_lazy_map_thingee {|h| h.look_for_needle()}
```

Comment: I think the answers given so far ignore that you have nested lists, right? I think you could improve the question by giving one or two small examples.

Comment: have you tried `haystacks.detect(&:look_for_needle).look_for_needle`. `detect` will return the first haystack with a needle and the secondary call to `look_for_needle` will return the Needle (assumption). Not sure how intensive `look_for_needle` is though.

Comment: Felix - The problem doesn't really have nested lists. It has a list of objects where an expensive operation is performed on each item.   engineersmnky - Yes, looking for needle in a haystack is an intensive operation.

Answer (score 12):

With Ruby 2.x [lazy enumerators](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator/Lazy.html):

```
needle = haystacks.lazy.map(&:look_for_needle).reject(&:nil?).first
```

Or:

```
needle = haystacks.lazy.map(&:look_for_needle).detect(&:itself)
```

Or (@DavidMoles):

```
needle = haystacks.lazy.filter_map(&:look_for_needle).first
```

Comment: I haven't verified it yet, but my gut says that this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Thumbs up for a lesson in lazy enumerators

Comment: As of 2.7 you can use [`filter_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map) to skip the `detect/reject` step: `haystacks.lazy.filter_map(&:look_for_needle).first`

Answer (score 1):

```
haystack.find &:itself
haystack.index &:itself
```

Which one do you prefer?

Comment: he is not looking for `nil` but rather the first instance where `look_for_needle` is not `nil`.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Corrected. The OP confused me with that needless initialization of `needle`.

Comment: To clarify, I don't want to return the first haystack that has a needle, I want to return the first needle that I find.

Comment: Then `#find` is your method of choice.

Comment: Nice except that this will return a haystack and not a needle. Also might want to caveat `itself` as this was not an Object method until 2.2

Comment: People should move on from Ruby `2.1.7` already :-) Method `#find` returns needle, not the haystack, but now I realize that the OP has multiple haystacks to search. Fortunately he knows how to iterater over them.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that both `find_proverbial_needle_in_a_haystack` and `look_for_needle` return the needle or `nil`, the latter if no haystack contains the needle.

```
class Haystack
  def initialize(haystack)
    @haystack = haystack
  end

  # Suppose look_for_needle is defined as follows
  def look_for_needle
    @haystack.include?(:straw) && :straw
  end 
end

def find_proverbial_needle_in_a_haystack(haystacks)
  needle = nil # can be anything
  haystacks.find { |haystack| needle = haystack.look_for_needle } && needle
end
```

`find` returns the first haystack for which the block evaluates `true`, or `nil` if no needle is found in any haystack.

```
haystacks = [Haystack.new([:ball, :top]),
             Haystack.new([:fluff, :straw]),
             Haystack.new([:dog, :cat])]
  #=> [#<Haystack:0x007fdaaa0f6860 @haystack=[:ball, :top]>,
  #    #<Haystack:0x007fdaaa0f67e8 @haystack=[:fluff, :straw]>,
  #    #<Haystack:0x007fdaaa0f6590 @haystack=[:dog, :cat]>] 
find_proverbial_needle_in_a_haystack(haystacks)
  #=> :straw 

haystacks = [Haystack.new([:ball, :top]),
             Haystack.new([:fluff, :yellow_stuff]),
             Haystack.new([:dog, :cat])]
  #=> [#<Haystack:0x007fdaaa082f50 @haystack=[:ball, :top]>,
  #    #<Haystack:0x007fdaaa082f00 @haystack=[:fluff, :yellow_stuff]>,
  #    #<Haystack:0x007fdaaa082eb0 @haystack=[:dog, :cat]>]     
find_proverbial_needle_in_a_haystack(haystacks)
  #=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ruby 2.0 and above, I extended Enumerable with this method:

```
module Enumerable
  TRUTHY_LAMBDA = lambda {|result| !!result }
  def first_result(detect_result_lambda=TRUTHY_LAMBDA, &block)
    self.lazy.collect(&block).detect {|result| detect_result_lambda.call(result) }
  end
end
```

With that you could call:

```
haystacks.first_result {|haystack| haystack.find_needle() }
```

..and it will return the needle.

If you needed to make sure it was a quilting needle, you could do this:

```
haystacks.first_result(lambda {|needle| needle&.for_quilting? }) {|haystack| haystack.find_needle() }
```

or the same code formatted with a do block:

```
haystacks.first_result(lambda {|needle| needle&.for_quilting? }) do |haystack|
  haystack.find_needle()
end
```

P.S. - if anyone can tell me how to improve this code to support the following syntax, that would be amazing (I get the error "SyntaxError: both block arg and actual block given" which suggests to me that Ruby is assigning "&:for_quilting?" to the &block rather than the first argument)

```
haystacks.first_result(&:for_quilting?) {|haystack| haystack.find_needle() }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `first` method which does precisely this.

It takes a block and returns the first match of the block

```
match = haystacks.first { |x| x.find_needle }
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-first

By the way, you can use `each` or `map` without too many more keystrokes:

```
match = haystacks.each { |x| break x if x.find_needle }
match = haystacks.map { |x| break x if x.find_needle }
```

though isn't really using the correct semantics of `each` or `map`, which you'd expect to return an array (`each` returns the original array and `map` returns a transformed array)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this returns the haystack. I don't want to return the first haystack that has a needle, I want to return the first needle.

Comment: you're right - in this case the 'break' approach would work because it exits the loop returning the specified value. tokland's `.lazy` approach works as well